# How do I use argparse to parse a matrix input?

Tags: python, numpy, argparse

I am new to argparse and I am trying to use it to input a 2D matrix in one command line (not seperate inputs). What is the best way to input a 2D matrix in argparse?

I have tried to use nargs, but it only allows me to input entries for one row of numbers.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-row1', action='store', type=int, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-row2', action='store', type=int, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-row3', action='store', type=int, nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I expect the user to specify the number of rows and so I'm not sure how to use the above code to dynamically allow the user to specify the number of rows and its contents.

Comment: I think your users should put the numbers in a `csv` style file, and just provide the file name in the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to make the argument format
`-nrows nb_rows -matrixdata  data_0_0 data_0_1 data_1_0 data_1_1 ...`

Then you can do:

```py
import numpy as np
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-matrixdata', action='store', type=int, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-nrows', action='store', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
m = np.array(args.matrixdata).reshape((args.nrows, len(args.matrixdata)//args.nrows))
print(m)
```

Which, for `-nrows 3 -matrixdata 1 2 3 4 5 6`, gives:

```
[[1 2]  
 [3 4]  
 [5 6]]
```